# Is there any function in weibullR package to get Reliabilty v/s Time graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, reliability

I am plottitng the reliability v/s time  plot in R using WeibullR package.
But by default it is printing Unreliability vs time.
Is there any way to make it reliability vs time graph??
Thanks in advance

library used:

library(WeibullR)

library(WeibullR)
df <- data.frame(time = c(10000, 10000, 20000, 20000, 30000,
                         30000, 30000, 30000, 40000, 50000,
                         50000, 60000, 70000, 70000, 70000,
                         70000, 80000, 80000, 80000, 80000,
                         90000, 90000, 100000),
                 event = rep(1, 23))
weibl <- 1- wblr(df, col="darkgreen",label="censored dataset", dist = "weibull2p", ylab = "check")
weibl_fit <- wblr.fit(weR, col = "Red", method.fit = "rr")
data <- wblr.conf(weibl_fit, col="blue")
plot(data)

Default it is plotting unreliability[%] vs Time to failure.
Expected is Reliability vs time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here df is the dataframe having time and event as the two column names. For below library it is required that your column names should in this format(viz: event and time).

To plot reliability vs time I'm using above df as input.

library(WeibullR)

weibl <- wblr(df, col="darkgreen",label="censored dataset", dist = "weibull2p", 
ylab = "Unreliability")

data <- wblr.fit(weibl, col = "Red", method.fit = "mle", dist = "weibull2p")
reliability<- data$data$dpoints

plot(x =reliability$time, y = ((1-reliability$ppp)*100), xlab = "Time", ylab = "reliability", xlim=c(1000,100000), ylim=c(0,100), col="orange")

Above plot will give you reliability vs time plot.